# Converting Char Array to Integer

Tags: c++, c

I fall into a interesting problem. When I first call string_to_int, stack created a memory buffer for size 6, and converted to a correct integer. But at the second call, IMO, stack reused the buffer (because smaller than size 6?), i still see content `"   513"` at the break point, so `atoi` converted to 56513 instant of 56.

How should I do array to int properly and fast ? I can't use `strtoi`, or `stoi` because the array can be sometimes fill by space only. i can't directly pass the array to `atoi` because the array (char stream from network), for example, can be "123456" but it actually contain 2 separate values "123" and "456"

```
    static int string_to_int(const char* number, int size)
    {
        char stackbuf[size];
        memcpy(stackbuf, number, size);
        return atoi(stackbuf);
    }

char* ptr1 = "   513"

string_to_int(ptr1, 6); //result = 513

char* ptr2 = "056"

string_to_int(ptr2, 3); //result = 56513
```

Comment: Since you're using C++, why not just use stringstream?  That way you avoid manual memory management and legacy C APIs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the `nul` terminator for `atoi` to work correctly, try `strcpy()` instead of `memcpy()` or copy `size + 1` bytes.

Comment: strncpy is a good option as it will also prevent from buffer overflow

Comment: @vishal `strncpy()` has its chance of mis-use too as it does not insure the the string end with `'\0'`.  Exactly the same problem OP is having here.

Comment: Thanks for the knowledge :)

Answer (score 2):

As noted by iharob, the issue is that in your 2nd case, you don't have a null-terminated string for atoi to work with.

```
static int string_to_int(const char* number, int size)
    {
        char stackbuf[size+1];
        memcpy(stackbuf, number, size);
        stackbuf[size] = '\0'; //or you could use strncpy
        return atoi(stackbuf);
    }
```

Comment: Sorry about that (or if you prefer <voice=SeanConnery>Something something, in the latin alphabet, Jehovah starts with an i</voice>)

Comment: He didnt have the terminating zero for the first case neither (there are 3 leading spaces). The zero was there out of luck

Comment: Using `strncpy()` in this context provides no benefit.